# Why do I need to click twice to run a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am using leaflet map and I am drawing some markers on it and when i click on a circle I run a submit form. This is the following code I am using.

**JS**

```
    // We draw the markers
    function drawMarkers() {

      if(stopAjax == false) {
        L.MarkerCluster.include({
          spiderfy: function(e) {
            var childMarkers = this.getAllChildMarkers();
            this._group._unspiderfy();
            this._group._spiderfied = this;
            if(childMarkers.length == 2) {
              clickMarkers();
            }
          },
          unspiderfy: function() {
            this._group._spiderfied = null;
          }
        });

        var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map);
        circles = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

        map.on("zoomend", function(){
          zoomLev = map.getZoom();
          console.log(zoomLev);
          if (zoomLev == 11){
            clickMarkers();
          }
        });

        function clickMarkers() {
          console.log("hello"); 
          circles.on('clusterclick', function (e) {
            $("#longiTude").val(e.latlng.lng);
            $("#latiTude").val(e.latlng.lat);
            submitSearchForm();
          },this);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
          var circle = new L.CircleMarker(coords[i].split(','))
          circles.addLayer(circle);
          circle.on('click', function (e) {
            var curPos = e.target.getLatLng();
            $("#longiTude").val(curPos.lng);
            $("#latiTude").val(curPos.lat);
            submitSearchForm();
          });
        }
        // we add the markers to the map
        map.addLayer(circles);
        // we empty the arrays for the future calls
        coords = [];
        // we set again stopAjax var to true to reset
        stopAjax = true;   
      }
    }
```

But on the click function, I need to click twice before it submits the form. Strange thing is that `console.log()` is happening at first click

```
        function clickMarkers() {
          console.log("hello"); 
          circles.on('clusterclick', function (e) {
            $("#longiTude").val(e.latlng.lng);
            $("#latiTude").val(e.latlng.lat);
            submitSearchForm();
          },this);
        }
```

Comment: ` circles.on('clusterclick', function (e) ` maybe try changing `clusterclick` to `click` ?

Comment: you should be able to add a class to the circles so you only need to bind click events once

Comment: @Petar circle.on('click' won't work since clusterclick is part of leaflet cluster plugin

Comment: @downfast aha ok, my bad, haven't worked with leaflet and that part seemed like some sort of "dblclick" so thought that may be it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it by removing

```
function clickMarkers() {
  circles.on('clusterclick', function (e) {
    $("#longiTude").val(e.latlng.lng);
    $("#latiTude").val(e.latlng.lat);
    submitSearchForm();
  },this);
}
```

And replacing

```
        if(childMarkers.length == 2) {
          clickMarkers();
        }
```

with

```
if(childMarkers.length == 2) {
   submitSearchForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think that's happened because you're defining an event inside a function who is inside another function.

Comment: I just tried to place that function outside the main function and still, needs double click. I am trying to set a click like this but I am writing the line wrongly `$(document).on('clusterclick', circles, function (e) {`

Comment: What about this?:

if(childMarkers.length == 2) {
              clickMarkers();
            }

Comment: ehmm, yes what about it?

Comment: could be many, but i stop the zooming if we have exactly 2 and if so, fire the click, as i said, it works, console log works, yet not firing the form untill the second clikc

Comment: Can I see this function? submitSearchForm();

Comment: function submitSearchForm() {
          $("#timeSearch" ).submit();
        }

Comment: Did you tried to put the console log inside the event? Try to debug if "e" has any valor please

Comment: Sorry then... I can't do so much. I hope that you find the bug and tell us why this happened :) Good luck!